# How to use compact.exe, the default Windows compression, in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, compression, command-prompt

I want to use the default Windows compression utililty for compressing a directory in a batch file. Currently I am using the following command, but it's not working.

```
COMPACT /C /S source destination
```

How do I use this from a batch file?

Currently, I am doing the same using [7-Zip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip), but I need to do the same with `compact.exe`.

```
START "Compressing Backup. DO NOT CLOSE" /belownormal /wait "%exe&Zip%" a -tzip -r -mx5 "%BackupFileDestination%" "%dirTempBackup%\"
```

Comment: does the command give you any output? compact doesnt have a "source destination" syntax btw, it just takes one argument

Comment: `compress.exe` does this but does not come on Windows by-default, and requires the Resource Kit. https://ss64.com/nt/compress.html |  https://ss64.com/links/windows.html | There's also the option to write a powershell script if you don't mind using PowerShell. | There's also the option to use the built-in CScript with a VBS script to do this: https://superuser.com/questions/110991 | I use this, personally: https://superuser.com/a/1217040/381054

Answer (score 3):

`compact` doesn't do what you think it does, I think:

> Displays or alters the compression of files on NTFS partitions. 
>   
>   COMPACT [/C | /U] [/S[:dir]] [/A] [/I] [/F] [/Q] [filename [...]]

It does the same as going to the folder properties and chosing "Compress contents to save disk space" - it does not create a [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) (or similar) archive.

```
COMPACT /C /S:"C:\Somefolder"
```

It will use [NTFS compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#File_compression) to shrink the folder on disk - not create a ZIP file, 7-Zip file or whatever.

Comment: `compact /C "c:\SomeFolder"` just marks the folder so that future additions are compacted: to actually compact the contents use /S: `compact /C "/S:C:\SomeFolder"`